# React Native Custom Android Keyboard

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to do a feasibility test for building a custom android keyboard using react native.

Has anyone had success with this? I've come across this for iOS, but I'm unable to find anything similar for Android: https://github.com/sahlhoff/react-native-keyboard-template

Answer (score -1):

I realize custom keyboard for iOS, I througt custom TextInput to weak up the custom keyboard, I think the principle is same, I hope it will help you.
[React-Native-Custom-Keyboard-iOS](https://github.com/newfun1994/React-Native-Custom-Keyboard)